# Rename multiple cell

Tags: excel, cell, vba

how to rename 12 cell at one time? I used below code but I dont seem it like a proper way because it is too long.

```
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C7").Value = "Jan"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D7").Value = "Feb"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E7").Value = "Mar"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F7").Value = "Apr"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G7").Value = "May"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H7").Value = "Jun"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I7").Value = "Jul"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J7").Value = "Aug"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K7").Value = "Sep"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L7").Value = "Oct"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M7").Value = "Nov"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N7").Value = "Dis"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an array directly:

```
Dim myArray As Array ' = ...

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C7:N7").Value = myArray
```

If you are using Excel VBA (Macro) you can declare your array this way:

```
Dim myArray() As Variant
myArray = Array("Jun", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May") 'etc
```

Comment: I think it should be `Dim myArray As Variant`? Anyways, deleted my answer :)

Comment: @L42 It's tested and working this way. The good point about this way is that it should work on VBA and VB.NET, because the OP seems to be talking about VBA but the question is tagged as VB.NET

Comment: A yeah my bad. It's tagged [tag:vb.net]. :) It's not gonna compile in VBA, dimensioning as array type. I was thinking `Dim myArray = Array("Jan","Feb"...)` though.

Comment: actually it vba not vb.net
so which one is correct :)

Comment: i already get the answer
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C7:N7") = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")